# Laravel eloquent DB seeder and array casting

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

can someone help me to understand how can I use attribute casting if I am inserting data with DB seeder (and retrieve it)

this is part of the seeder

```
    DB::table('events')->insert([
    [
            'title' => 'prizes',
            'description' => serialize([
                    "text" => "General description..."
                    ]),
            'language' => 'en',
            'time_start' => null,
            'time_end' => null,
            'lat' => null,
            'lng' => null,
    ]
]);
```

this way I do have serialized data in my database, but when I do

```
$events = Event::with('user')->where('child','=',null)->get();
```

I get description is null

(don't worry about user its null by default)

this is my Event model

```
class Event extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'events';
    //
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User','id');
    }
    protected $casts = [
        'description' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: Try `json_encode` instead.

Comment: @thefallen yea it works like that, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting), Eloquent array casting serializes array into JSON:

> The array cast type is particularly useful when working with columns that are stored as serialized JSON

So you should insert it like this:

```
DB::table('events')->insert([[
    'title' => 'prizes',
    'description' => json_encode(["text" => "General description..."]),
    'language' => 'en',
    'time_start' => null,
    'time_end' => null,
    'lat' => null,
    'lng' => null,
]]);
```

As a side note, [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) belongs to PHP core and it does not produce JSON.